# SubQuery PHP show 0 as result

Tags: php, mysql

i trying to make a report but this query returns 0, can you help please?
this report will show in a table the result of this query. The query is ok, i use directed in DB and worked  [check the image of the query running direct in DB[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4VYl.png)

```
$seleciona4 = "SELECT rel1.grupo,
               (SELECT count(1)
                FROM relatorios.relatorio rel2
                WHERE rel2.grupo  = rel1.grupo
                AND rel2.status = 'Em Análise') as count_analise,

        (SELECT count(1)
                FROM relatorios.relatorio rel2
                WHERE rel2.grupo  = rel1.grupo
                AND rel2.status = 'Aguardando Correção') as count_correcao,

        (SELECT count(1)
                FROM relatorios.relatorio rel2
                WHERE rel2.grupo  = rel1.grupo
                AND rel2.status = 'Em trabalho') as count_trabalho,

        (SELECT count(1)
                FROM relatorios.relatorio rel2
                WHERE rel2.grupo  = rel1.grupo
                AND rel2.status = 'Pendente usuário') as count_usuario,

        (SELECT count(1)
                FROM relatorios.relatorio rel2
                WHERE rel2.grupo  = rel1.grupo
                AND rel2.status in ('Em Análise', 'Aguardando Correção', 'Em trabalho','Pendente usuário')) as count_total


        FROM   relatorios.relatorio rel1
        WHERE  rel1.grupo != 'O2A'
        GROUP BY rel1.grupo
        ORDER BY 6 DESC;";

$resultado4 = mysql_query($seleciona4) or die(mysql_error());
?>
<br><br>• Non-Workable
<Table border>
<tr>
    <td>Grupo</td>
    <td>Em Analise</td>
    <td>Aguardando correção</td>
    <td>Em Trabalho</td>
    <td>Pendente Usuário</td>
    <td>Total</td>
</tr>

<?php
while($tb_inc4 =  mysql_fetch_array($resultado4) ){
    $tb_inc4= (object)$tb_inc4;

    $grupo4 = $tb_inc4->grupo;
    $analise4 = $tb_inc4->analise;
    $correcao4 = $tb_inc4->correcao;
    $trabalho4 = $tb_inc4->trabalho;
    $usuario4 = $tb_inc4->usuario;
    $total4 = $tb_inc4->total;

    echo "<tr>
            <td>$grupo4</td>
            <td>$analise4</td>
            <td>$correcao4</td>
            <td>$trabalho4</td>
            <td>$usuario4</td>
            <td>$total4</td>
          </tr>";
}
?></table>
```

Comment: Does the code get to the while loop? Have you var_dumped $resultado4 (`echo var_dump($resultado4);`)?

Comment: You're likely having some error in your query that you aren't seeing. I'd split up your mysql_query() OR die() statement into 2 and do a var_dump on resultado4 like Jan suggests.  You probably will want to also print out the mysql_error() results.

Comment: Is the error now mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,

Answer (score 1):

You should use conditional aggregation.  A simpler query might help you locate your problem:

```
SELECT r.grupo,
       SUM(r.status = 'Em Análise') as count_analise,
       SUM(r.status = 'Aguardando Correção') as count_correcao,
       SUM(r.status = 'Em trabalho') as count_trabalho,
       SUM(r.status = 'Pendente usuário') as count_usuario,
       SUM(r.status in ('Em Análise', 'Aguardando Correção', 'Em trabalho','Pendente usuário')) as count_total
from relatorios.relatorio r
where r.grupo <> 'O2A'
group  by r.grupo
order by 6 desc
```

Note that the query does not end in a semicolon.  Application interfaces often do not like that.  Speaking of which, you should be using mysqli_ or PDO, which are both currently supported.

Comment: Is the error now mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,